# how to initialize struct node-ffi struct

Tags: node.js, struct, node-ffi

I have library on linux. 
That library have struct. 
Manual of this library says that struct must be initialized, like this:

```
LONG lUserID;
NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 struDeviceInfo;
lUserID = NET_DVR_Login_V30("192.168.1.64", 8000, "admin", "12", &struDeviceInfo);
```

struDeviceInfo — output data from device, that I must to read and use.
How can I code this in Nodejs. 
PS: I use node-ffi module, library initialization and connect to device finished ok.

```
    var net = require('net');
    var events = require('events');
    var util = require('util');
    var request = require('request');
    var xml2js = require('xml2js');

    var ffi = require("ffi");
    var ref = require("ref");
    var ref_struct = require("ref-struct");    

var libHikSDK = ffi.Library('./libhcnetsdk.so', {
    'NET_DVR_Init': ['bool', []],
    'NET_DVR_SetConnectTime': ['bool', ['char', 'char']],
    'NET_DVR_SetReconnect': ['bool', ['char', 'bool']],
    'NET_DVR_Login_V30': ['char', ['string', 'int', 'string', 'string']],
    'NET_DVR_Cleanup': ['void', []],
    'NET_DVR_GetLastError': ['char', []],
    'NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion': ['char',[]],
    'NET_DVR_SetLogToFile': ['bool',['int', 'string']]
    });

libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Cleanup();
var init = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Init();
var v = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion();
var s = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_SetConnectTime('200000', '1');
libHikSDK.NET_DVR_SetLogToFile(3, "/home/user");
var i = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Login_V30("192.168.0.10", 8000, "admin", "12345");
var g = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ref-struct` to define `NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30` structure and then adjust function definition like this:

```
const NetDvrDeviceInfoV30 = StructType({...});

const libHikSDK = ffi.Library('./libhcnetsdk.so', {
  ...
  'NET_DVR_Login_V30': ['char', ['string', 'int', 'string', 'string', NetDvrDeviceInfoV30]],
  ...
});

const netDvrDeviceInfoV30 = new NetDvrDeviceInfoV30();
const i = libHikSDK.NET_DVR_Login_V30("192.168.0.10", 8000, "admin", "12345", netDvrDeviceInfoV30);
```